# Logistic Regression with 3-level categorical factor

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I am trying to analyze a dataset in which I have a binary DV, one continuous IV, one 2-level categorical IV, and one 3-level categorical IV. I initially thought of running a binary logistic regression, but then I didn't get all pairwise comparisons for the 3-level categorical variable (which I would like to have).

This is the code I used to run the binary logistic regression in `R`. Because it requires a reference level for each factor, it only returns two pairwise comparisons (not 3) for my 3-level categorical factor:

```
myregression <- glm(myDV ~ Continuous_IV + 2level_IV + 3level_IV, family="binomial", data=mydata) 
summary(myregression)
```

Is there a better way to analyze this dataset? Should I do regression with the other variables and then just Chi-squared, ANOVA, or *t*-tests for the 3-level IV? However, I'm a little stuck because I can't look for interactions with the other variables with this approach. Thanks!

Comment: The model you fitted is a fairly standard way to model this type of data. You can get the pairwise comparisons from the `emmeans` package.

Answer (score 6):

The model you fitted is a fairly standard way to model this type of data. Just because there is a reference level and thus one contrast "missing", this is easily overcome by some simple arithmetic, but you can get the pairwise contrasts directly from the `emmeans` package:

```
emmeans(myregression, pairwise ~ 2level_IV + 3level_IV)
```

As an example, here is a noddy simulation. It isn't a glm, but that won't matter as far as explaining one way to do you want is concerned.

```
library(emmeans)
dt <- expand.grid(catvar1 = c("A", "B"), catvar2 = c("M", "N", "O" ), reps = 1:5)
dt$y <- rnorm(nrow(dt), 0, 1)

m0 <- lm(y ~ reps + catvar1 + catvar2, data = dt)
emmeans(m0, pairwise ~ catvar1 + catvar2)
```

and this produces:

```
$contrasts
 contrast  estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
 A M - B M   0.0227 0.334 25   0.068  1.0000
 A M - A N   0.2662 0.409 25   0.651  0.9857
 A M - B N   0.2889 0.528 25   0.547  0.9935
 A M - A O   0.5960 0.409 25   1.457  0.6932
 A M - B O   0.6187 0.528 25   1.172  0.8459
 B M - A N   0.2435 0.528 25   0.461  0.9971
 B M - B N   0.2662 0.409 25   0.651  0.9857
 B M - A O   0.5734 0.528 25   1.086  0.8825
 B M - B O   0.5960 0.409 25   1.457  0.6932
 A N - B N   0.0227 0.334 25   0.068  1.0000
 A N - A O   0.3298 0.409 25   0.806  0.9637
 A N - B O   0.3525 0.528 25   0.667  0.9840
 B N - A O   0.3072 0.528 25   0.582  0.9914
 B N - B O   0.3298 0.409 25   0.806  0.9637
 A O - B O   0.0227 0.334 25   0.068  1.0000
```

which should have all the pairwise contrasts you mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `marginaleffects` package to get the pairwise comparisons from the model.  Below is an example where I simulate a dataset like the one you describe, and then compute the pairwise differences

```r
library(marginaleffects)
library(tidyverse)

n <- 250
cat_var <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], size=n, replace = T)
bin_var <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)
cont_var <- rnorm(n)

X <- model.matrix(~cont_var + cat_var + bin_var)
beta <- c(-2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.45, -0.3)
p <- plogis(X %*% beta)
y <- rbinom(n, 1, p)

d <- tibble(cat_var, cont_var, y)

# Now, fit the model
fit <- glm(y~cont_var + cat_var-1, data=d, family = binomial())


avg_comparisons(fit, 
                variables = list(cat_var = "pairwise")
                )
#> 
#>     Term Contrast Estimate Std. Error      z Pr(>|z|)   S   2.5 % 97.5 %
#>  cat_var    B - A  0.00543     0.0515 0.1055    0.916 0.1 -0.0955  0.106
#>  cat_var    C - A  0.01002     0.0534 0.1876    0.851 0.2 -0.0947  0.115
#>  cat_var    C - B  0.00459     0.0511 0.0898    0.928 0.1 -0.0956  0.105
#> 
#> Columns: term, contrast, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high 
#> Type:  response
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Note that the estimated differences are on the probability scale.

The appropriateness of this approach depends on your intent, so I suggest editing your question to add detail about the data, the outcome, and what you're trying to answer.